# HTML5 File API NotSupportedError

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, fileapi

I can't get the File API system to work using any of the tutorials that I've found.  I've tried all of these in order to get the code to work.

```
window.storageInfo.requestQuota(PERSISTENT, size, success, error);

navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(size, success, error);

window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, size, success, error);
```

The first two give me this error:

NotSupportedError: The implementation did not support the requested type of object or operation.

And the last one gives me this error:

SecurityError: It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources.

If anyone knows how to fix this, the I would appreciate it.  I tried everything I can possibly think of.
I thought (--allow-file-access-from-files) might be the solution, but it didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SecurityError might be caused by your file not being on a web server. Once your file is on a web server, window.requestFileSystem() should work in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  I was wondering if that question was ever going to get answered.

Comment: I think I have the same issue.  I'm trying to create a new file using FileSystem API.  What do you mean when you said "file not being on a web server"?  Isn't everything local?

Comment: Find the reason for my SecurityError.  Chrome cannot be in Incognito Mode.

Comment: @woran that solved my issue, please add it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

This error get's triggered if you run `requestQuota` in inkognito mode